# Trying to filter out nulls and it isn't working

Tags: sql, oracle

Oracle SQL newbie here.

I have three columns that contain a lot of null values. I'm trying to filter out all rows that have null values for all three columns.

However, it's still returning null values for the coalesce formula below. Any ideas?

```
select name, city, attribute1, attribute2, attribute3
from table1
where coalesce(attribute1,attribute2,attribute3) is not null
```

I've tried doing the same thing with the CONCAT formula but got the same results. I was able to get it to work when I used nvl(attribute1,'None') in the CONCAT formula but I was hoping there was an easier way.

EDIT: I'm still not getting the right results. I'm posting the full query below. Perhaps there's another error in my syntax.

```
select 
gjb.name "Batch",
gjl.attribute_category,
gjh.name,
gjh.created_by,
gjh.period_name,
gcc.segment1,
gcc.segment2,
gcc.segment3,
gcc.segment4,
gcc.segment5,
gcc.segment6,
gjl.attribute1,
gjl.attribute2,
gjl.attribute3,
gjl.attribute4,
gjl.attribute5,
gjl.attribute6,
gjl.attribute7,
gjl.attribute8,
gjl.attribute9,
gjl.attribute10,
nvl(gjl.entered_dr,0)-nvl(entered_cr,0) "Amt"

from gl_je_lines gjl, gl_je_headers gjh, gl_je_batches gjb, gl_code_combinations gcc
where not (gjl.attribute1 is null 
and gjl.attribute2 is null
and gjl.attribute3 is null
and gjl.attribute4 is null
and gjl.attribute5 is null
and gjl.attribute6 is null
and gjl.attribute7 is null
and gjl.attribute8 is null
and gjl.attribute9 is null
and gjl.attribute10 is null)
and gjl.je_header_id = gjh.je_header_id
and gjh.je_batch_id = gjb.je_batch_id
and gcc.code_combination_id = gjl.code_combination_id
and gjb.je_source in ('Manual','Spreadsheet')
and gjh.period_name in (:Period)
and upper(gjb.name) not like '%BEGBAL%'
and gjl.status = 'P'
```

Comment: this should work, you really get results that have null in all 3 with this statement?

Comment: @Ab Bennet has the right idea. By using coalesce, you are defeating the ability for the optimizer to use constraints and indexes. As to why your code isn't working, please provide a small sample data set that illustrates this issue.

Comment: I am with @Hogan - this should work.  Are you sure there are no spaces in the JE Lines DFF columns?   The contents of the columns will vary by journal source - and Spreadsheet could import just about anything

Comment: @BrianLeach  I edited my original post. I'm still getting an error. Any ideas? Thanks for your help.

Comment: is the issue because you have extended your filter condition to be on attribute4 onwards as well. Is this the desired result? That where not (...) above will only return rows where at least one of the attributes is filled in. If attribute4 is filled in but 1 to 3 aren't that row will still be returned.

Comment: @Dan Please be specific, what error are you getting?

Answer (score 3):

```
Select ......
Where not( attribute1 is null
And   Attribute2 is null
And   Attribute3 is null)
```

Comment: Seems like the most simple solution.

Comment: ?? mixing not( ... is null and ... is **not** null)  think there 2 not's too many

Comment: yeh my bad, forgot to fix it

Comment: @AbBennett I'm still not getting the right results. I've edited my original post to show everything I'm doing.

Comment: i added comment above. If still not working, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is doing:   "filter out rows that have null values in any of the three columns"

You seem to want:  "filter out rows that have null values for all three columns".

You might as well be specific about the `NULL` comparisons:

```
select name, city, attribute1, attribute2, attribute3
from table1
where attribute1 is not null or attribute2 is not null or attribute3 is not null;
```

For the "any" version, just change `or` to `and`.

Comment: I'm using Oracle BI Publisher and the OR statements takes forever to run in this environment. Any ideas without using the OR statement?

Comment: @Dan . . . This type of query would seem to need a full table scan.  You must have a really big table.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the size of the code, I am posting this as another answer rather than just a comment to your question. It makes your SQL easier to understand if you switch to ANSI join syntax, and check for not null:

```
SELECT gjb.name "Batch"
     , gjl.attribute_category
     , gjh.name
     , gjh.created_by
     , gjh.period_name
     , gcc.segment1
     , gcc.segment2
     , gcc.segment3
     , gcc.segment4
     , gcc.segment5
     , gcc.segment6
     , gjl.attribute1
     , gjl.attribute2
     , gjl.attribute3
     , gjl.attribute4
     , gjl.attribute5
     , gjl.attribute6
     , gjl.attribute7
     , gjl.attribute8
     , gjl.attribute9
     , gjl.attribute10
     , NVL (gjl.entered_dr, 0) - NVL (entered_cr, 0) "Amt"
  FROM gl_je_lines gjl
       INNER JOIN gl_je_headers gjh ON gjl.je_header_id = gjh.je_header_id
       INNER JOIN gl_je_batches gjb ON gjl.je_header_id = gjh.je_header_id
       INNER JOIN gl_code_combinations gcc
           ON gjh.je_batch_id = gjb.je_batch_id
          AND gcc.code_combination_id = gjl.code_combination_id
 WHERE (gjl.attribute1 IS NOT NULL
     OR gjl.attribute2 IS NOT NULL
     OR gjl.attribute3 IS NOT NULL
     OR gjl.attribute4 IS NOT NULL
     OR gjl.attribute5 IS NOT NULL
     OR gjl.attribute6 IS NOT NULL
     OR gjl.attribute7 IS NOT NULL
     OR gjl.attribute8 IS NOT NULL
     OR gjl.attribute9 IS NOT NULL
     OR gjl.attribute10 IS NOT NULL)
   AND gjb.je_source IN ('Manual', 'Spreadsheet')
   AND gjh.period_name IN (:period)
   AND UPPER (gjb.name) NOT LIKE '%BEGBAL%'
   AND gjl.status = 'P'
```